# GetElementByTagName[ 0 ].setAttribute inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I just curious about this.

I created an function that add ID value to a dynamically create li tag.

the function looks like this.

```
function limenu(lix,liy){
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].setAttribute("id",lix);
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].setAttribute("id",liy);

} limenu("icon-dice","icon-clock");
```

My thought is, can I use an for-loop? that let me insert how many events I want without need to create  `document.getElementsByTagName("li")[1]-[2]-[3]`.. etc

so when i call the function liemenu(), I would be able to add as many events i want.

I could use Jquery but i really want to do this with Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you simply tried it?

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;i++)`

Comment: I tried for a while, but couldn't get the count right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function limenu() {
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var count = Math.min(lis.length, arguments.length);
    for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        lis[x].setAttribute('id', arguments[x]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/72hdS/